# How to display or print the contents of a database table as is?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to fetch a table from a database using Java code. The sample code which I tried gets only two columns. I want the fetched data to be presented exactly like it is in the table.
How do I do that ?

This code only gives me two rows, side by side -

```
while (rs.next()) {
System.out.println(rs.getString(4) + " " + rs.getString(6));

}
```

Full example at -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342339.aspx

```
This is what I tried - 

         int size = 0;
         if(rs != null){

            rs.beforeFirst();  
            rs.last();  
            size = rs.getRow();  

         }

         System.out.println("cols = " + size);
```

And got an error - The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.

Comment: ... you print out the other columns...

Comment: @MitchWheat - I want to get the number of columns in a result set and then print them out. The api has no method like getNumberOfColumns();

Comment: this has been solved.

Comment: @skyscraper - Please kindly to answer the question by providing your preferred solution here, to let the other knows.. ;)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/31887249/32453

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this code

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
```

Source - [How to get the number of columns from a JDBC ResultSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614416/how-to-get-the-number-of-columns-from-a-jdbc-resultset)

After using that code, one can display the results like they are displayed by the DBMS as follows -

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();                     

// Iterate through the data in the result set and display it. 

while (rs.next()) {
//Print one row          
for(int i = 1 ; i <= columnsNumber; i++){

      System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + " "); //Print one element of a row

}

  System.out.println();//Move to the next line to print the next row.           

    }
```

Column names are not displayed in this example.

Answer (score 20):

I posted this answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475896/system-out-println-from-database-into-a-table/26735511#26735511), but I believe this one is also relevant, maybe more so. In short, I wrote a simple utility class to print db table rows to standard out (for part fun, part learning). It may be useful to someone (at least I hope so).

Here is the link to the code repo at GitHub: https://github.com/htorun/dbtableprinter

And here is the basic usage:

```
// Create a connection to the database
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

// Just pass the connection and the table name to printTable()
DBTablePrinter.printTable(conn, "employees");
```

It should print something like this:

```
Printing 10 rows from table(s) EMPLOYEES
+--------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
| EMP_NO | BIRTH_DATE | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | GENDER |  HIRE_DATE  |
+--------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
|  10001 | 1953-09-02 | Georgi     | Facello   | M      |  1986-06-26 |
+--------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
|  10002 | 1964-06-02 | Bezalel    | Simmel    | F      |  1985-11-21 |
+--------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your code only get 2 value of the row. Notice that `rs.getString(4)` meant, get the value on **current row** at **4th column** (using 0 based index) as `String`.

If you want to print all the column, you should write the rest `rs.getXXXX()`, where `XXXX` is column data type such as `getString(), getInteger(), getLong(), etc`. See this java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) for reference.

Comment: If you want to get each row value, you should iterate `rs` variable. If you want to get row size, please check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset)

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void printSqlTable(String selectQuery) {
      try {
           Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
           resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectQuery);
           DBTablePrinter.printResultSet(resultSet);
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```